# Gradients in Visual Studio 2015 theme

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to make VS 2015 to look more like VS 2008.

I've installed [Color Theme Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2015ColorThemeEditor), and attempted to make some gradients. However, visual studio ignores the gradient, and uses only one of gradient colors.

Does VS 2015 not support gradients at all?